# UIDatePicker count Down timer mode doesn't return the correct time in Xcode 10.3

Tags: swift, countdown, uidatepicker

I'm working on a project in which the user can select a time interval (HH:mm) from a `UIDatePicker` in **count down mode** and, with that time interval, I want to trigger a notification.

I created the `UIDatePicker` in the Storyboard and set the *Mode* to **Count Down Timer** in the *Attributes Inspector*.

The problem is that when I get the current value of the datePicker, the value is never correct.

For example, if the user selects 1 minute, I get random values between 70 an 110 but never 60!
How is this possibile?
(The problem occurs with every selection)

This is how I get the current value:

```
timePicker.countDownDuration
```

and for testing purpose, I print it with

```
 timePicker.countDownDuration.description
```

Maybe there is a bug or something that I don't know? (of course there is)

I tried to convert the value represented on the `UIDatePicker` in string a then, reconvert it in `TimeInterval` but if there is a better method it would be great.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.  We can't help you find the error if we can't see what you have done.

Comment: I can't add all the cose because is useless for the problem. I want to print the countdownduration precisely but the datepicker don't let me to do it... The two lines that I have posted are all the code related to the UIDatePicker so there isn't "other code"

Comment: Have you implemented a `@objc func pickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        print(sender.countDownDuration) }` and added it like: `picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerChanged), for: .valueChanged)`.  What does it show?

Comment: Read my answer.. probably it's an xcode bug. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok problem solved, maybe it's a bug of XCode.

The problem occurs when you build the `datepicker` from storyboard and set  it's mode paramether to `Count Down Timer`.
To solve this problem, simply don't set the mode of the `datepicker` on `count down timer` from the storyboard but you need to set the mode programmatically with

```
timepicker.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
```

Doing this, the problem is solved

Comment: Weird.  I am able to confirm this behavior and solution. It certainly seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Although broken in Xcode 10.3, it seems to be working fine in Xcode 11 beta 5.

Comment: I seem to recall this is mentioned in the release notes.